# How to wrap content before string value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, contains

I have a list of:

```html
<li> key1 : value1 </li>
<li> key2 : value2 </li>
```

and want to wrap the `keys` with `<b>`. As shown

```html
<li> <b>key1</b> : value1 </li>
<li> <b>key2</b> : value2 </li>
```

Comment: can you separate the "keys" into spans or some other html construct?  This will avoid some cumbersome and possibly error-prone parsing.

Comment: no can't use any html tags, what if i seperate them with # instead of :

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var content;
$("li").each(function(){
  content = $(this).text().split(":");
  $(this).html("<b>" + content[0]+" </b>: "+ content[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').each(function(){
        var text = $(this).text().split(':'); 
        $(this).html('<b>' + text[0] + '</b>:' + text[1]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

More concise versions of the other answers:

```
$('li').html(function(i, html) {
    return html.replace(/([^:]+)/, '<b>$1</b>');
});
```

```
$("li").html(function(i, html) {
    var content = html.split(":");
    return "<b>" + content[0] +"</b>:"+ content[1];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

And the regexp solution

```
$('li').each(function(){
    var el = $(this);
    el.html( el.text().replace(/([^:]+)/,'<b>$1</b>') );
})
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/tjVeR/

Comment: [There's a more concise way to write that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915761/jquery-wrap-content-before-string-value/6916202#6916202)

Comment: @Eric +1, right.. i was breaking my mind trying to remember how to do it without `.each` and i could not see the obvious.. nice catch.